# How to remove GRUB password requirement

Tags: grub2, password

Initially I configured GRUB to require a password when GRUB loads ubuntu.
Now I need to remove the password protection from GRUB.
I have commented out the superusers account and its associated password (password_pbkdf2) in the /etc/grub.d/00_header file. Yet even after a reboot and a hard shutdown I am still being prompted when GRUB loads.

Could someone please advise me on what else I need to do?

Thanks in advance,
Don

Comment: This might be a dumb question to ask, but did you run `sudo update-grub` after you did the changes and before the reboot?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I needed. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The file may be /etc/grub.d/40_custom or 00_header or the file you used to save password.

To find out

```
grep password /etc/grub.d/*
```

then

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/<file-name>
```

Remove or comment out the superusers account and its associated password or password_pbkdf2

and of-course

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Not sure but should there be a space between `password` and `/etc`?